# Can I change the slope of contents on a page without changing the page layout? Place table sideways?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want my document to remain in the Portrait Layout and some are tables and they would fit on a page if presented in Landscape. I do no not want to present them in photo format for easy editing. I am using MS 2010. Can someone assist me on how to go about this?

Comment: You can rotate individual pages to landscape. Is that also out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

### Put the table in a Textbox and rotate the textbox.

Note that textboxes cannot extend over more than one page. They can, though, be linked.